# Recycler view VISIBILITY problem, it goes offscreen

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

When I set something visible in my recycler view "visibility = VISIBLE" it goes offscreen if its close to bottom or top, I wanted to know if is there any way to make the recyclerview focus in it when VISIBLE is called.

I tried using moveTo with no succes I think it works only with views that have the same size.

```
p0.itemView.constraintLayout.visibility = VISIBLE
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzqb3.png]

I wanted it to move up instead of going offscreen by scrolling a bit up or something when click.

Comment: use p0.itemView.constraintLayout.visibility = INVISIBLE

Comment: I want it to be visible, i just dont want it to be visible offscreen or down the scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved with scroll and some delay:

```
Timer().schedule(100){
                        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)
                    }
```

Comment: really after following my answer , you gave same answer yourself and accepting your  answer (copy of mine)

Answer (score 2):

You can scroll to that item's position

> (when you make any particular item visible , just scoll to that item's
>   position -> so it will be in focus)

```
yourRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(yourItemPositionInTheAdapter).
```

Note:- `yourItemPositionInTheAdapter` is the item position which you made visible and want to focus